# How to use LinkedIn People Search API

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

As there are several changes in LinkedIn People Search API as of now,please explain how to use this API for people search by company and etc...

I have read

- https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

and other document but not getting connection with search link and **API key** and all.As explained in document we can search some thing like this

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?keywords=Princess

but where we need to put **API KEY** and all. I am new to APIs so please if possible explain this.

- I have also go through other blogs but they are old and not applicable.
- If possible please also mention possibility and things we cann't do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LinkedIn's People Search API has not been available to the open developer community since May, 2015.

You can apply to be a developer partner at: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

If you are an official partner of LinkedIn and still have access to that API, you should follow up with your assigned Partner Engineering representative for further assistance, rather than public forums.

Comment: Please explain the details if possible

Answer (score 0):

Use Postman to follow this tutorial:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

On succes you can click [image] to get the PHP code you need to create the request with OATH2. I have no developer account on LinkedIn so that part you have to do yourself.

The example GET request would look like this in PHP:

## Step 2

```
<?php

$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;

$request->setRequestUrl('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization');
$request->setRequestMethod('GET');
$request->setQuery(new http\QueryString(array(
  'response_type' => 'code',
  'client_id' => '123456789',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin',
  'state' => '987654321',
  'scope' => 'r_basicprofile'
)));

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
));

$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();

echo $response->getBody();
```

## Step 3

```
<?php

$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;

$request->setRequestUrl('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken');
$request->setRequestMethod('POST');
$request->setQuery(new http\QueryString(array(
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
  'code' => '987654321',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/auth/linkedin',
  'client_id' => '123456789',
  'client_secret' => 'shhdonottell'
)));

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => 'bee6f5d7-a0e6-4a76-6ef8-930c95af53a6',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'host' => 'www.linkedin.com'
));

$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();

echo $response->getBody();
```